# Ternary operator and html

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to output some html in view inside the ternary operator:

`<%params[:type]=="0" ? "<span class=\"active\">Links</span>" : link_to("Links",:type=>0)%>`

It doesn't work as instead of link or span element it outputs me html tags `<span class="active">Links</span>`
I'm new to ruby/rails, tried to move <%= %> tags, but can't find a way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try with [raw method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/RawOutputHelper/raw):

```
<%= params[:type] == "0" ? raw("<span class=\"active\">Links</span>") : link_to("Links",:type=>0) %>
```

or the [html_safe](http://apidock.com/rails/String/html_safe):

```
<%= params[:type] == "0" ? "<span class=\"active\">Links</span>".html_safe : link_to("Links",:type => 0) %>
```